# How not to use http_proxy for internal servers- Linux

Tags: linux

This may be a simple question but i am not able find an answer in Google.

I have a proxy server set in http_proxy and also there is internal server which i am not able to reach via proxy.

How can i configure my machine so that for these internal servers proxy should not be used?

Answer (score 0):

I have in my .bashrc these lines:

```
   export http_proxy=http://192.168.1.15:5187/
   export https_proxy=$http_proxy
   export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
   export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
   export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

You may try something similar. I have had some difficulty because some programs search for the all-cap versions of the very same shell variables. If you need more options, [this Web page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/proxy_settings) of my favorite distro will tell you more.